# Are ByteBuddy's field setting checks too strict?

Tags: byte-buddy

I am using [`MethodCall.setsField()`](https://javadoc.io/static/net.bytebuddy/byte-buddy/1.10.17/net/bytebuddy/implementation/MethodCall.html#setsField-net.bytebuddy.description.field.FieldDescription-) to try to set an instance field on another instance.

My generated class that is doing the field-setting, `GC`, is trying to set the value of an instance field in an instance of something it has created (`CI`).  So the field's declaring type is `CI`; my field-setting code resides in `GC` (which is in the same package as `CI` but otherwise unrelated to it).

The [ByteBuddy checks seem to indicate that although `GC` and `CI` are in the same package, `GC` must be assignable to `CI` in order to set this field](https://github.com/raphw/byte-buddy/blob/0e8e61ec6926a0df78e709fc19fe41f0b660e440/byte-buddy-dep/src/main/java/net/bytebuddy/implementation/MethodCall.java#L3115-L3116)!  That greatly surprised me, but I am not a bytecode expert, and I might very well be overlooking something obvious.  Could someone kindly explain why this check is necessary?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The method call sets the field implicitly on the *this* instance on which the method is invoked. For this to be possible, a non-static field must be declared by a super type of the type on which the method is invoked.

If you think this is too strict, please file an issue with an example of the code you are trying to generate, including the code to generate it which is currently failing. Maybe I am not thinking straight about this and if there's a restriction to be lifted, I would surely do it.

Comment: OK; I was trying to use it to set an instance field on a different instance.  I guess it works as it does, then.  I'll ask in another StackOverflow question about how to implement this use case.

Comment: See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64625192/from-a-bytebuddy-generated-method-how-do-i-set-a-public-instance-field-in-an