# From a ByteBuddy-generated method, how do I set a (public) instance field in an object received as an argument to the return value of a MethodCall?

Tags: byte-buddy

I am generating a class in ByteBuddy.

As part of one method implementation, I would like to set a (let's just say) `public` instance field in another object to the return value of a `MethodCall` invocation.  (Keeping the example `public` means that access checks etc. are irrelevant.)

I thought I could use [`MethodCall#setsField(FieldDescription)`](https://javadoc.io/static/net.bytebuddy/byte-buddy/1.10.17/net/bytebuddy/implementation/MethodCall.html#setsField-net.bytebuddy.description.field.FieldDescription-) to do this.

But from my [prior question related to this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64582521/are-bytebuddys-field-setting-checks-too-strict) I learned that `MethodCall#setsField(FieldDescription)` is intended to work only on fields of the instrumented type, and, looking at it now, I'm not entirely sure why or how I thought it was ever going to work.

So: is there a way for a ByteBuddy-generated method implementation to set an instance field of another object to the return value of a method invocation?

If it matters, the "instrumented method" (in ByteBuddy's terminology) accepts the object whose field I want to set as an argument.  Naïvely I'd expect to be able to do something like:

```java
MethodCall.invoke(someMethod).setsField(somePublicField).onArgument(2);
```

There may be problems here that I am not seeing but I was slightly surprised not to see this DSL option.  (It may not exist for perfectly good reasons; I just don't know what they would be.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not possible as of Byte Buddy 1.10.18, the mechanism was originally created to support getters/setters when defining beans, for example. That said, it would not be difficult to add; I think it would even be easiest to allow any custom byte code to be dispatched as a consumer of the method call.

I will look into how this can be done, but as a new feature, this will take some time before I find the empty space to do so. The change is [tracked on GitHub](https://github.com/raphw/byte-buddy/issues/968).